# How to put meta tag image reference in slim ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, metadata, slim-lang, twitter-card

The favicon tag with image works fine

```
=favicon_link_tag "favicon.png", rel: "shortcut icon", type: "image/png"
```

At the same time I could not find a solution to make meta tag image reference in slim

```
meta name="twitter:image" content="social-thumb.png"
meta property="og:image" content="social-thumb.png"
```

These are the social media tags which needed to fix with images

Comment: Where did you placed `social-thumb.png` file?

Comment: @asiniy same folder as other images stored

Comment: Can you say me the path of the `same folder`?

Comment: @asiniy fixed with `image_url()` and thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 1):

You will be laughing, but

```
meta name="twitter:image" content="social-thumb.png"
meta property="og:image" content="social-thumb.png"
```

Check it out [here](http://slim2html.raving.systems/).

Comment: What's html output of these lines?

Answer (score 1):

Finally the bugs have been fixed with `image_url('social-thumb.png')`

```
meta name="twitter:image" content="#{image_url('social-thumb.png')}"
meta property="og:image" content="#{image_url('social-thumb.png')}"
```